How can multiple items be published simultaneously in Sitecore while creating only a single publishing job?
I am currently working with Sitecore 10.1 and using the Sitecore Publishing Service. I have a requirement to publish multiple items with a single click using a custom button in the ribbon. For example, if we are on a Page item with associated datasources, clicking the button should update the workflow of the Page and its datasources, then publish both in a single operation, creating only one publishing job.
I attempted to add the publishing options to an array and then publish them using the Publishing Manager. However, this approach resulted in multiple jobs being created in the Publishing Dashboard instead of a single publishing job.
PublishManager.Publish(publishOptions)

As far as I know, there is no option like that.
In Sitecore you can either publish a single item (with subitems or/and related items) or you can trigger full site publish.
You cannot specify a list of items and create a single publishing job that would execute the process for you.
